# Sorting vector of blocks C++ SFML

Tags: c++, sorting, sfml

I just wanted to make a little program to sort blocks using selection sort, but it doesn't sort itself. Blocks just keep switching places in some pattern, until I terminate the process.

I think there is something wrong with the swaping of the blocks, but to be honest I'm really lost.

I will appreciate any help from you guys.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace sf;
int main()
{
    RenderWindow win(VideoMode(200, 200), "SFML works!",Style::Titlebar);
    win.setFramerateLimit(60);

    std::vector<RectangleShape> blocks;
    for(int i=1;i<=10;i++)
    {
        RectangleShape block(sf::Vector2f(20,20*i));
        block.setOrigin(block.getSize().x,block.getSize().y);
        block.setOutlineColor(Color::Red);
        block.setOutlineThickness(0.5f);
        //block.setPosition(i*20,200);
        blocks.push_back(block);
    }
    std::random_shuffle(blocks.begin(),blocks.end());
    for(int i=1;i<=10;i++)
        blocks[i].setPosition(i*20,200);
    bool t = false;
    while (win.isOpen())
    {
        Event event;
        while (win.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == Event::Closed)
                win.close();
            if(event.type == Event::KeyPressed)
            if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::Space)){
                if(t){
                    t = false;
                    std::cout<<"KLIK"<<"\n";
                    break;
                }
                    t = true;

                std::cout<<"KLIK"<<"\n";
            }
        }

        win.clear();

        for(auto a:blocks)
            win.draw(a);
        if(t){
        int k;
        for(int i=0;i<blocks.size();i++)
        {
            win.clear();
            for(auto a:blocks)
                win.draw(a);
            win.display();
            k = i;
            for(int j=i+1;j<blocks.size();j++)
                if(blocks[j].getSize().y < blocks[k].getSize().y)
                    k = j;
            Vector2f temp = blocks[k].getPosition();
            blocks[k].setPosition(blocks[i].getPosition().x,blocks[i].getPosition().y);
            blocks[i].setPosition(temp.x,temp.y);
            //std::cout<<i<<"\n";
        }

    }

        win.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can start by describing what the code is supposed to do, what the goal is and what the actual results are.

Comment: Basiclly it creates a window and fills a vector array with a rectangles of diffrent sizes.Then it shuffells the array to make it unsorted and renders everything on the screen.Between frames it should sort the array but all it does it makes it move in a weird way.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

First you have an exception `out_of_range` here:

```cpp
for(int i=1;i<=10;i++)
    blocks[i].setPosition(i*20,200);
```

Remember that in c++ you index from 0 and when you use `push_back()` 10 times in the vector you have indexes from 0 to 9

Solution:

```cpp
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    blocks[i].setPosition((i+1)*20,200);
```

---

Secondly, in selection sort, you still need to replace the indexes in the vector so that the sorted values are in front.

Solution:

```cpp
Vector2f temp = blocks[k].getPosition();
blocks[k].setPosition(blocks[i].getPosition().x,blocks[i].getPosition().y);
blocks[i].setPosition(temp.x,temp.y);
std::swap(blocks[k], blocks[i]);
```